# Why can't I use an "if" statement to return true/false in a PHP function?

Tags: php

Why does it not work to use an `if` statement to determine if a function should return true or false? True works, but false doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
function test($var){
    if($var == "string"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Doing: 
`echo test("string");` returns `true` as it should, but using `echo test("hello");` should return `false`, but returns nothing, why?

What should be used instead for returning true/false with criteria?

Answer (score 5):

Well it does [work on my side](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab6053c64dc7784b43cab90b25b39df4982a50a5)

Using :

```
function test($var){
    if($var == "string"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

echo "string:";
var_dump(test("string"));
echo "hello:";
var_dump(test("hello"));
```

cause the output

> string:bool(true)
>   hello:bool(false)

When you want see the output of something always use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-dump.php) as false produces no output when echoed directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump(test("hello"));
```

Echoing false deceptively produces no output. Try `var_dump` instead; it will show you the true value.

```
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why your code doesn't work, but this would be shorter:

```
function test($var) {
    return ($var == "string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is dangerous - this means probably wrong.

Use === instead of ==

```
if ($var === "string") { ...
```

Read the doc ;)